# Distinct values ignoring a field in Spring Data Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

In my spring boot app utilizing mongodb I am trying to get a list of distinct nested objects.

The document looks like this (other details removed fore brevity):

```
class Movie {
  otherproperties...;
  List<CastRoleLink> cast;
  ...
}

//structure of CastRoleLink
class CastRoleLink {
  String name;
  String urlName;
  String roleID;
}

//additional class for structure of results
class CastLink {
  String name;
  String urlName;
}
```

What I really want is a list of all the unique `CastLink` from all of the `Movies` matching my criteria, which means that I need all of the distinct `CastRoleLink` objects without the `roleID`.  The tricky part is that for different movies I could have the same `name` and `urlName` properties but a different `roleID` property.  In these cases I would consider them the same because the `CastLink` would be the same.  My current solution is close but not quite right.

```
//query is Query object with criteria for Movies
mongoTemplate.findDistinct(query, "cast", Movies.class, CastLink.class);
```

This gives me duplicates when the `name` and `urlName` properties are the same but the `roleID` property is different.  Is there a way that I can find distinct `name` and `urlName` objects while ignoring the `roleID` property?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The key is to use Aggregation.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
  match(criteria),
  unwind("cast"),
  group("cast.urlName").addToSet("cast.name").as("name").addToSet("cast.urlName").as("urlName")
  project("name").and("urlName").previousOpertaion(),
  sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name")
)

return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Movie.class, CastLink.class).getMappedResults();
```